# Create Certificate with Openssl

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate

I want to know the command to create a certificate with Openssl.

I have and example of one and it star with:

```
-------BEGING CERTIFICATE-------
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hi I found the following command, it create a certificate and create a privatekey.

In this command you could change the extension of the file, I use .pem you could use whatever you want.

```
Openssl req -nodes -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout PrivateKey.pem -out Certificate.pem -days 730 -subj /
```

`[-days 730]` here you can change the period of the certificate will ve available
`[-subj /]` this is optional if you don't want to fill the information that the certificate ask you. (country, city, etc)